# Where is the line drawn between "no improvement whatsoever" and "causes harm"?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, suggested-edits

I was in the suggested edits review queue today, when I came across possibly the worst edit I've reviewed. It was almost entirely changes along the lines of replacing `"I haven't"` with `"i havent"`. It removed backtick code formatting. It also removed proper indentation off of half a code block, and added way too much indentation on the other half.

I rejected the edit for *"causing harm"*. It un-formatted code and actively ruined spelling and grammar. However, the two other reviewers who rejected the edit gave the *"no improvement whatsoever"* reason. I can understand this, as the changes "actively harm readability" and don't improve anything, but I would expect an edit as aggressive as that to qualify for "causes harm".

What guidelines should I follow when rejecting an edit for "causes harm"? Was I right to reject it that way, or was "no improvement" a better reason?

Comment: This should better be rejected as vandalism.

Comment: It hardly matters which reason you pick, as long as it reasonably describes the problem. On bad edits like this, just about any reason in the box is suitable. Don't agonize over the choice, just click reject as fast as you can.

Comment: Somehow I would pick reject and edit...

Comment: I just want to mention that this _might_ have been a merge botch.  Specifically, I've seen things like this happen when the OP posted something with poor formatting and grammar, and Alice went through and fixed all the formatting and grammar problems, and _while she was doing that_ Bob went in to correct one small content error, but by the time Bob hit "submit" Alice's edit had already been approved. The system isn't clever enough to recognize that Bob's starting point was before Alice's edit so it records a revert of most of her work.

Comment: (To be clear, such botched edits _should_ be rejected -- it's just that it's not Bob's fault.)

Comment: @zwol That is what happened, actually. I didn't notice that until after, but the edit didn't give me the impression that it was done with malice, so I didn't mark it vandalism.

Comment: @zwol: "The system isn't clever enough to recognize that Bob's starting point was before Alice's edit so it records a revert of most of her work." Why is that? It doesn't seem to be very difficult to implement such a feature. A simple solution such as detecting Bob's edit started before Alice submitted her edit should already avoid such problems.

Comment: @morxa Indeed, handling this type of situation correctly via "three-way merge" is a basic feature of every version control system newer than CVS, and yet neither Stack Exchange nor Wikipedia has it.  I would certainly support a feature proposal to do three-way merges but I am not going to initiate one.

Comment: @zwol: A short notice "The post has been edited since you started editing. [show change]. Do you want to continue?" would already be an improvement and would avoid the need for a merge (although ultimately, merging is the way to go).

Answer (score 41, accepted):

There are some guidelines under each reason in the reject dialog.

> #### no improvement whatsoever
>
> This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read, easier to find, more accurate or more accessible. Changes are either completely superfluous or actively harm readability.
>
> #### causes harm
>
> Describe how this edit would make the post worse.

The preset reason "Changes are either completely superfluous or actively harm readability." seems to cover this case.

"Causes harm" is a custom reject reason, where you can explain why the edit causes harm, when the reason does not fit one of the presets.

I wouldn't worry too much about using one of the presets versus the custom message so long as either describe the real problem. The important thing here is the bad edit was rejected.