# The gradations in the edit rejection reasons are insufficient

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, suggested-edits

I suggested some (minor) edits on a question ([see it here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/19309543) ). It was rejected as "not an improvement, changes superfluous, actively harms readability" which on the face of it is ridiculous, but I've rejected some edits and had to struggle to choose one of the stated reasons - and it's always been a rather poor fit: wouldn't it be better to maybe provide a pre-cooked list of reasons, but also allow for "Other" with an explanatory comment?

Comment: I'm not sure why that edit has been rejected. For me, improving the grammar or a question and adding articles improves the question.

Comment: I obviously agree, but the point was more about the misleading reason given. Of course as @Servy points out, there *is* such an option (I'm sure I have seen it but I forgot about it), so clearly the people who rejected it chose the expeditious route of *not* writing an explanation of what they meant - but there is not much that can be done about that.

Comment: I'd be borderline on rejecting that edit because polishing a turd. The only reason I'd be borderline is because the tables were at least formatted decently. It's still a gib me teh coedz turdish question.

Comment: As far as I can see, one of the reviewers rejects every suggestion and the other one thinks fixing grammar is not a good enough reason to suggest an edit. I believe both of them are wrong. @Will shouldn't the question be at least closed to reject with that reason?

Comment: @ayhan: I had the same idea to check the review history. And I also found both reviewers history a bit problematic. This specific edit was borderline because of the question quality, but in general, I would approve edits that fix the grammar of a post as long as all the grammar problems are fixed.

Comment: @ayhan possibly. But editors should definitely concentrate their efforts on questions likely not to be closed because they are off topic for one reason or another.

Comment: @ayhan There is a strategy some use in the edit review queue to skip anything you would Approve because there are enough robo-reviewers that anything left alone will get Approved anyway. So a reviewer with nearly all rejects isn't necessarily rejecting a bunch of good edits but may be skipping them instead.

Comment: Adding to @BSMP 's remark: When you're limited to 20 reviews you sometimes don't want to use them up on things that will get OK'd from the "rank-and-file".

Answer (score 4):

There is:

[image]

Comment: Also related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356344/clarify-suggested-edit-rejection-reasons-by-changing-causes-harm-to-custom-re

Comment: Thanks for the reminder that there *is* such an option and (to @ayhan) for the pointer to the "custom option" discussion.